# Is Tukey's Predicted Least Squares an actual test?

Tags: post-hoc

A letter in a recent (2011) article of Nature doi:10.1038/nature09817 refers in several places to a Fisher's predicted least-square difference test.  A google search returns 102 hits for "predicted least square difference" and 3 for "predicted least squares difference".  The first two pages seem to mostly come from journal articles and none of the ones I checked included a citation.  Those that reported the use of a particular analysis package tended to mention StatView.  However, StatView seems to have been swollowed by SAS at some point and then disappeared.  In the only version of their [manual](http://ec1.images-amazon.com/media/i3d/01/A/man-migrate/MANUAL000054749.pdf) I found refered to a PLSD but called it a "Protected Least Significance Difference" post-hoc.  That term has 9980 results on google, again mostly journal articles.  Is it safe to assume this is really just a regular Tukey LSD post-hoc that has been only run when the omnibus ANOVA was judged to be statistically significant?

Comment: I would try to contact the authors of that Nature article..

Comment: I considered it.  However there there are enough  other papers that claim to use the same statistic that it seemed more appropriate to discuss the point here if only to provide a web resource for those who have a similar question.